# Parseador de JSON chequear entero es Nulo en Java Android

Tags: java, android, json

Recibo un JSON que a veces los campos numéricos tienen valor o bien `null`:

```
{
   duration: null
}
```

Justo en la sentencia:

```
jArray.getJSONObject(id).getInt("duration");
```

Se produce el error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at duration of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de intentar obtener el valor, puedes utilizar [`isNull`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)) para verificar si el valor es null o no existe.

Ejemplo:

```
JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(id);
if (!obj.isNull("duration")) { 
    valor = obj.getInt("duration");
}
```

Si necesitas saber si efectivamente el valor es null (existe pero es null), es un poco mas complicado.

```
if(obj.has("duration") && obj.isNull("duration")) { 
   // el valor existe, pero es null. 
}
```

Como habitualmente, null pude tener un significado *tristate*, tendras que considerar cada caso antes de tomar tu decision.

Ademas, ya lo dice la respuesta anterior, también esta [`optInt`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String)) (y optString, optLong, etc), pero este método te dará el valor por defecto, incluso si el campo no fue establecido en absoluto. Así que deberías optar por una u otra opción de acuerdo a las necesidades del caso.

Comment: Pues si, vale tenerlo en cuenta, dependiendo del propósito si quieres guardar como null o con otro valor

Answer (score 2):

Para parsear nulos a entero se debe remplazar `getInt` por `optInt`:

```
.optInt("json_field");
```

o bien podemos especificar un entero para `null`:

```
.optInt("json_field",0);
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
jArray.getJSONObject(id).optInt("duration",0);
```